# Обработка клика по элементу массива

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавлять/удалять класс при клике кнопку?

Дан массив объектов, при клике на кнопку к элементу должен добавляться класс `active`, при повторном клике этот класс должен убираться.
Пробовал через useState, но так класс добавляется ко всем элементам.

Также пробовал через `ref`, но почему то через `classList.add('active')` не происходит добавление ‍♂️

Код:

```
import React from 'react'

function Card({ items }) {

  const onSelectItem = (item) => {
    ...?
  }

  return items.map((e, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={`${e.id + i}_${i}`} className="card">
          <div className="card__controls">
            <div
              className="card__fav button button--shadow"
              onClick={() => onSelectItem(e)}>
              <svg>...</svg>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  })
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете хранить состояние в самом массиве для каждого элемента:

```
import React from 'react'

function Card({ items, setItems }) {

 // вместо индекса лучше использовать уникальный ключ каждого элемента, если есть
  const onSelectItem = (item, index) => {
    setItems(items.map((v, idx)=>index===idx ? {...v, isActive: true} : v ))
  }

  return items.map((e, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={`${e.id + i}_${i}`} className="card">
          <div className="card__controls">
            <div
              className=`card__fav button button--shadow ${e.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`
              onClick={() => onSelectItem(e, i)}>
              <svg>...</svg>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  })
}

export default Card
```

Или вам нужно будет создать useState массив с активными состояниями элементов items.

Comment: огромное спасибо! :)